# What is the best session based test management tool for larger companies with groups of 10-15 testers?

Tags: test-management

What is the best session-based test management tool for larger companies? We have multiple test engineer groups, some with up to 7-8 testers.

Are there any professional tools to support larger organizations?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by session-based, but my last company used HP ALM to manage test cases and that was pretty good.  I guess it was kinda buggy but it worked well enough

Comment: Session based testing is where you don't have scripted test cases, but instead test in sessions of 1-2 hours, following a mission and document your findings along the way. It's a more free way of testing and would require some skill from the test engineers.

Comment: Ah then ignore my answer, mine was in reference to scripted test case repository, not session based.

Comment: In HP ALM you can as well skip detailed scripting of test cases, but still use its functionality to integrate requirements, test cases (just basic description of them in your case "mission") and bug-tracking ("document your findings along the way"). But anyway you can not just use exploratory testing ("more free way of testing"), especially in larger companies. BTW I'm agree with @GKS1 hp alm is a buggy tool, that is not suitable for proprietary software.

Answer (score 0):

I once had a similar demand on a Scrum based project and we used JIRA, so this answer is dependant on that.

We set up a new sub-issue type and created the necessary fields for Session based metrics.  Then we tied those sessions directly to the story when it was being tested which helped us track our progress.  We then used the JIRA API to pull out the necessary information for reporting.